# Why we need permission "android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" to send Sticky Broadcast

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

Why we need permission "android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" to send Sticky Broadcast ? why not for normal broadcast ? what makes it special to define permission in Android Manifest ?

Answer (score 2):

> Why we need permission "android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" to Receive Sticky Broadcast ?

You do not need [the `BROADCAST_STICKY` permission](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#BROADCAST_STICKY) to receive a sticky broadcast. You need that permission to *send* a sticky broadcast.

Comment: Ops..thanks.why do we need permission to send sticky ? y not for normal broadcast ?

Comment: @421: Presumably because a sticky broadcast lives for the life of the phone, and they do not want system RAM cluttered up with too many of those broadcasts. That is just a guess, though.